# Is it possible to change order of attributes when toJson()?

Tags: java, json, pojo, to-json

Let's take this example. I have a pojo class as below.

```
public class MyRecord{
    private String name;
    private String id;

    //constructors and getters,setters
}
```

when I get the toJson(new MyRecord("MyName","myId") output for above I can get.

```
{
  "name": "MyName",
  "id": "123" 
}
```

And I have inherited one as follows to add the dateTime.

```
public class MyRecordWithDateTime extends MyRecord{
        private String DateTime;           

        //constructors and getters,setters
}
```

so when I called toJson(new MyRecordWithDateTime("2016-01-01", "MyName", "myId"))

The output is this

```
{
  "name": "MyName",
  "id": "123",
  "dateTime": "2016-01-01" 
}
```

but I actually need that as follows. (dateTime should come first.)

```
{          
  "dateTime": "2016-01-01", 
  "name": "MyName",
  "id": "123"
}
```

Is there anyway to do that with keeping inheritance?

Comment: Object fields/members do not have an order (nor should they). If you need members ordered you should use a list/array structure

Comment: @RichardH if you have looked closely Json.toJson() extracts fields by getters and exactly follows the order of getters. i.e. If you skip a getter for some field, it will not appear. The reason I asked this is, I wonder whether there are any annotation at least.

Comment: Relying on the order in which the getters are written in your class is terrible design. You'd be better off calling the getters yourself in the order you want

Comment: But that's how JSON.toJson() works. It's the library implementation and I cannot do anything about that. The problem about changing the order is "How can I do that for an inherited class?" as in my example. It extracts the parent class getters first.

Comment: But that is my point: class fields do not have an order. If you want fields or values ordered you need to use a data structure that has an order, i.e an array, list or ordered hash of some sort.

Comment: may i ask why you need this ? just curious

Comment: @Yazan its just for presentation purpose. Indeed there is a front-end client who can work with this json, without worrying about the order. But if we refer the rest service directly anyway, the order I want, is pretty clear to understand. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field/member/attributes in a JSON collection do not have an order, and as far as this JSON data structure is concerned, the "order" doesn't matter.

The only reason I can imagine you are concerned with the order is for printing/presentation purposes. In that case I suggest you manually construct the JSON string yourself.

Comment: So does your answer implicitly suggest that ->"Don't worry about the order of keys, at all when you creating JSON responses" ???

Comment: Correct. JSON is just a string representation of a javascript object. The order of keys in a javascript object absolutely does not matter - indeed there is no order defined. If you want to print out a JSON string with the keys in a particular order you'll have to implement this yourself instead of relying on a library method.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe kinda late but just in case there is this annotation @JsonPropertyOrder

Answer (score 1):

Before you put it in your JSON file, you can try to make an ordered List ( LinkedList, ArrayList or something like), then sort it as you want and after that put it in JSON.

But obviously, a better idea than mine exists!!

But the fact is: JSON doesn't need to be sorted! You just use the getter and it will find your value associated to the key! Even if it's in the last position.

Comment: I can't get you. I want to change the order of fields??

Comment: Just use a list in your constroctor. Something like : `private LinkedList<Object> values = new LinkedList<Object>(); ` Object is an example. Here it's a String

Comment: I can use a List as you propose, but that changes the response format in terms of indentation right?

Comment: Imagine you have you LinkedHashMap (name : linkHM) sorted and completed properly :
`JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> elem : linkHM.entrySet()) {
           jo.put(elem.getKey(),elem.getValue());     
}`

Comment: But to do that, I should completely move from object nature right? which is some what conflicting.

Comment: I can't understand what you said. I didn't tried what I said, but I think it could work. The order: (1)you initialize the LinkedHashMap, (2)you put the elements in the order ( with name as the key, and the value as a string (or not, Json preserves the type))  (3) you create the JSONObject with the for statement I posted above, and (4) your write the JSONObject into the file!